# How to deduce this puzzle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education, puzzle

Every station on the railway system sells tickets to every other station. Some new stations were added. 46 sets of additional sets of tickets were required. How many new stations have been added? How many stations were there originally

Ans: 2 new stations (11 existing stations)

I don't know how to get to this answer.
Please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's suppose that there used to be $n$ stations, and that $k$ new stations were added. Every station sells tickets to every other station, so prior to the new stations being added, each of the $n$ stations sold tickets to $n-1$ different destinations, meaning that there used to be $n(n-1)$ sets of tickets. *After* the new stations were added, there were $(n+k)(n+k-1)$ sets of tickets. Hence, the number of new sets of tickets is $$\begin{align}46 &= (n+k)(n+k-1)-n(n-1)\\ &= (n+k)^2-(n+k)-n^2+n\\ &= (n+k)^2-n^2+n-n-k\\ &= \bigl((n+k)+n\bigr)\bigl((n+k)-n\bigr)-k\\ &= (2n+k)k-k\\ &= (2n+k-1)k.\end{align}$$

---

At this point the idea is to try to find a factor $k$ of $46$ such that $\frac{46}k=2n+k-1$ for some integer $n,$ or equivalently, such that $$\frac12\left(\frac{46}k-k+1\right)\tag{$\star$}$$ is an integer. Furthermore, since $n$ and $k$ are both numbers of train stations, it really doesn't make sense for $k$ or $n$ to be negative, and we certainly can't have $k=0$. So, we want to find a *positive* factor $k$ of $46$ such that $(\star)$ is a *nonnegative* integer. The positive factors of $46$ are $1,2,23,$ and $46,$ so there aren't too many cases to check. It turns out that $(\star)$ is an integer for *all* such values of $k,$ but it is negative for $k=23$ and $k=46.$ Consequently, we have $k=1$ or $k=2,$ which correspond (respectively) to $n=23$ and $n=11.$

Hence, one of the two following two must be true (hat tip to Gintas K for noticing that there were, in fact, *two* possibilities allowed by the chain of equations above):

- There were $23$ stations, and $1$ more station was added.
- There were $11$ stations, and $2$ more stations were added.

Now, if we take "some new stations were added" to mean that more than one station was added, then we can conclude that the second case must be the one that occurred.

Comment: The answer could be 1 new station and 23 existing stations also?

Comment: Right you are, @Gintas! That's definitely worth noting.

Comment: It might be quicker to note that you need $2nk$ new tickets for each pair of new and old stations ($nk$ going from old to new, and $kn$ going from new to old) and $k(k-1)$ new tickets for each pair of new stations, for a total of $2nk+k(k-1)=46$ new tickets.

Comment: Nice counting argument @Barry! I like it.

Comment: @CameronBuie, thanks.  Alternatively, think of each station as responsible for printing tickets for its departing trains.  Then each of the $n$ old stations needs to print $k$ additional tickets, and each of the $k$ new stations needs to print $n+k-1$ tickets, for a total of $nk+k(n+k-1)=46$ additional tickets.

Answer (score 1):

When there are $n\geq1$ existing stations and $k\geq1$ new stations we need $2nk+k(k-1)$ new sets of tickets. From
$$k(2n+k-1)=46$$
we conclude that $k\in\{1,2,23,46\}$. Trying  $k=1$ we get $n=23$, trying $k=2$ we get $n=11$, and both cases are compatible with the story. On the other hand, the values $k=23$ and $k=46$ do not lead to an admissible $n$.